# Demora muito a consulta em mysql

Tags: sql, query, select

Ola amigos estou tendo uma dificuldade em encontrar o que esta errado no meu código de selecção (SELECT) em mysql, esta a demorar mais de 70sec não sei porque. Alguém ai pra me ajudar por favor?

Código:

```
SELECT id_aluno, nome_aluno, ano_lectivo, data data_pagamento_m, nome_classe, codigo_classe, nome_curso, valor_curso1, multa
FROM tb_matriculas
LEFT JOIN tb_classe ON tb_matriculas.classe = tb_classe.id_classe
LEFT JOIN tb_curso ON tb_curso.codigo_curso = tb_matriculas.curso
WHERE  data_pagamento_m < '$data_nova '
AND data_pagamento_m <> '2017-01-01'
AND YEAR(data_pagamento_m) = '$ano_select'
AND classe BETWEEN '$classe1'
AND '$classe2'
AND classe <> '10'
AND curso BETWEEN '$curso1' AND '$curso2'
AND turma BETWEEN $turma1 AND $turma2
AND periodo BETWEEN '$periodo1' AND '$periodo2'
GROUP BY id_aluno
```

Comment: crie índices para sua tabela, que resultará em mais velocidade na sua  pesquisa

Comment: Qual o motivo de `GROUP BY id_aluno`?

Comment: Outra dúvida, tem certeza que é `LEFT JOIN`, recomendo leitura: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)

Comment: Ola obrigado, já criei um  indece na tabela tb_matriculas, o GROUP BY id_aluno para agrupar por aluno

Comment: Rode um EXPLAIN de sua consulta e analise o resultado.

Comment: A function YEAR quebra um índice se houver na coluna de data_pagamento_m , e parece ter um problema de modelo pois pagamento é atributo de que tabela ? Há um só pagamento ?

Comment: Você utiliza a cláusula GROUP BY mas não utiliza nenhuma função de agregação em sua lista de seleção. O que deseja agrupar?

Answer (score -1):

Se a tabela tiver muitos registros e esta consulta for muito recorrente ou importante retornar com rapidez crie um índice contendo todos os campos usados na cláusula WHERE.

Reveja as cláusulas com BETWEEN que recebem STRING que podem comprometer a query, como os seguintes:

```
AND classe BETWEEN '$classe1' AND '$classe2'
AND curso BETWEEN '$curso1' AND '$curso2'
AND periodo BETWEEN '$periodo1' AND '$periodo2'
```

O tratamento das strings funciona mas caso tenham IDs será muito mais rápido de executar.

Altere os LEFT JOIN para INNER JOIN conforme indicado pelo @Marconi, pois como as cláusulas são sobre alunos que devem estar em classes, cursos e períodos indicados não faz sentido fazer um LEFT JOIN. Este ponto dependerá da sua regra de negócio.